# Can not add jquery in footer

Tags: plugins, footer

I am trying to load the script in footer but always it shows that it is added in header.

```
function tabbed_scripts()  
{  
wp_register_script( 'tabbed-scripts', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.responsiveTabs.min.js', __FILE__ ) );   
wp_enqueue_script( 'tabbed-scripts' );  
 }
```

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tabbed_scripts' );

How can I move script to footer?

Comment: Please read wordpress codex carefully before paste any question.

Answer (score 2):

You must remember there is $in_footer parameter with [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) function.
By default it is set to false. Try setting it to TRUE(I don't see you doing it) and the jQuery should appear in your footer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this

```
    function tabbed_scripts() {  
       wp_enqueue_script( 'tabbed-scripts', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.responsiveTabs.min.js', __FILE__ ), array(), false,true);   
    }  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tabbed_scripts' );
```